# Is it possible to remove parts from the Ribbon, in VSTO Excel C# Document-Level Customizations?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ribbon

Is it possible to remove parts from the Ribbon, in VSTO Excel C# Document-Level Customizations?

For example, I want to disable the Data Tools group in the Ribbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you should be able to do

1. Create a new Excel Workbook project
2. Right click on solution - Add item = **Ribbon XML**
3. follow the steps in the newly generated class
4. edit the generated Ribbon.xml file like this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
    <ribbon>
     <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabData" visible="false">

      </tab>
     </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>`

When I run the project I can't see the Data tab in my Excel